# Долгий insert в mysql

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

Сайт на основе Moodle.

Структура таблицы следующая.

```
CREATE TABLE mdl_disc_cont_iup
(
  id          INT AUTO_INCREMENT
    PRIMARY KEY,
  bup_regnum  VARCHAR(255)                        NULL,
  group_name  VARCHAR(255)                        NULL,
  sem_bup     INT                                 NULL,
  sem_iup     INT                                 NULL,
  control     VARCHAR(50)                         NULL,
  mark        CHAR(255)                           NULL,
  disc_block  VARCHAR(50)                         NULL,
  full_name   VARCHAR(500)                        NULL,
  login       CHAR(255)                           NULL,
  person_id   CHAR(16)                            NULL,
  date_insert TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NULL,
  arc         INT DEFAULT '0'                     NULL
);
```

Для вставки встроенный метод

```
$DB->insert_records('disc_cont_iup', $records);
```

Он объединяет записи по 50 штук и отправляет на вставку.
Без отключения автокоммита, индексов и т.д.

Но всё это выполняется катастрофически долго, нужно импортить раз в сутки 400к записей

> Переписал я напрямую через mysqli, комбинируя по 500 записей, но по
>   прежнему медленно. Скрипт получает эти записи http запросом, и затем
>   должен в кроне их импортить.
>   Сейчас около 1000 записей в минуту

Comment: Ну наплюйте на этот "встроенный метод", делов-то.

Comment: а если объединять не по 50 а по 500 или 1000? объединяет это ведь `insert into ... values (row1), (row2), (row3)` ? и нужен ли тут пхп  в принципе, не обойтись командной строкой? там по 400к так и будет накапливаться постоянно в таблице?

Comment: Сейчас попробую переписать чисто mysql объединив по 1000

Comment: @Akina не вышло

Comment: "получает эти записи http запросом" - так что именно медленно? Получение записей по http или запись в базу?

Comment: @Мелкий речь только про вставку

Comment: Я должен был уточнить. А то встречаются люди, 99% времени ждущие сеть и спрашивающие как ускорить >1% времени работы базы. Здесь были: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-optimization.html ? Наиболее производительный способ в mysql - собрать данные в csv и скормить напрямую через `LOAD DATA INFILE` запрос.

Comment: что внутри `insert_records`? может проблема в её реализации

Comment: Какова будет скорость, если те же 1000 записей закинуть во временную таблицу, а потом выполнить обновление данных из неё? И - структура таблицы не предполагает контроля дублирования данных (не считая синтетического первичного ключа). А нет ли контроля софтом?